# Build a max heap and Iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I have two questions:

**1)** Recently I'm try to build a [max heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).  Even though I read [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) I can't find the bug as I run it. The following is my code...

```
def maxHeapify(list, index):
    int = index
    left = (int+1) * 2 - 1
    right = (int+1) * 2
    largest = 0
    if left < len(list):
        if (left <= len(list)) & (list[left] >= list[int]):
            largest = left
        else: 
            largest = int
    if right < len(list):
        if (right <= len(list)) & (list[right] >= list[largest]):
            largest = right
    else:
        pass
    if largest != int:
        listNew = swapWithinList(list, int, largest)
        listNew = maxHeapify(listNew, largest)
    else:
        return listNew


def swapWithinList(list, id1, id2):
    num1 = list[id1]
    num2 = list[id2]
    listNew = list[:id1]
    listNew.append(num2)
    listNew = listNew + list[(id1+1):id2]
    listNew.append(num1)
    listNew = listNew + list[(id2+1):]
    return listNew
```

I give input but the console just says:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listNew' referenced before assignment
```

does it mean that I put the return statement on the wrong line or there's something I haven't mentioned?

**2)** What is a iteration?

I am a bit embarrassed when I ask the question. But what is a iteration? Wiki says each repetition of the process means it, so is it a result the loop gives each round?

And iterator seems a basic element in Python, what's difference between iterator and iteration?

Comment: If `largest == int`, then you don't define listNew, then you try to return listNew.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use the built-in heapq module?

Comment: @hayden: So if `largest == int`, I have nothing to return since there's no _listNew_?

Comment: @user1277476: Actually I don't know there's the built-in heapq module. What should I do to call it for use?

Comment: [`import heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) it's installed by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1:

Without further comments, here's the code adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap):

```
def max_heapify(A, i):
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2
    largest = i
    if left < len(A) and A[left] > A[largest]:
        largest = left
    if right < len(A) and A[right] > A[largest]:
        largest = right
    if largest != i:
        A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
        max_heapify(A, largest)

def build_max_heap(A):
    for i in range(len(A) // 2, -1, -1):
        max_heapify(A, i)
```

Example:

```
def ptree(A, i=0, indent=0):
    if i < len(A):
        print '  ' * indent, A[i]
        ptree(A, i * 2 + 1, indent + 1)
        ptree(A, i * 2 + 2, indent + 1)

A = range(9) 
build_max_heap(A)
ptree(A)
```

Result:

```
 8
   7
     3
       1
       0
     4
   6
     5
     2
```

Let us know if you have any questions.

2:

Iteration in python is technically a process of repeatedly calling some object's `next()` method until it raises the `StopIteration` exception. Object that possesses this `next` method is called Iterator. An object that is able to provide an Iterator for the calling code is called Iterable.

Comment: Thank you! So _iteration_ is a process that keep calling the `next()` method, and I call _iterator_ to execute the `next()` method. But what is the WP article? I [google](http://www.google.com) it and it turn out to be wordpress article?

Comment: @lucasKoFromTW: sorry, I meant the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Comment: Thanks! But after I modify the code, it prints out `IndexError: list index out of range`. I can't find the bug since the notation of _left_ and _right_ have nothing wrong. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if largest != int:
        listNew = swapWithinList(list, int, largest)
        listNew = maxHeapify(listNew, largest)
    else:
        return listNew
```

If the if statement is false, you try to return listNew, but listNew might not exist at this point (it's only assigned to if the if statement is true).

An iteration is just a pass through a loop or in general, a single pass through some larger thing. Iterators are objects are iterate through data structures, or go through the elements one at a time.

Comment: Thanks! But where should I put the return statement? Or what should I do to fix the code?

Comment: You can return there, if that's where you're wanting to return. However, you need to add code to make sure listNew is actually initialized before returning it. e.g. if you're sure that the "largest != int" part will run at least once, initialize it to null somewhere, otherwise do something.